# Обернуть каждые 7 элементов через js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Есть списко

ul
  li
  li
  li
  li
/ul

как обернуть каждые 2 li ещё в ul через js чтобы получилось так

ul

ul
  li
  li
/ul

ul
  li
  li
/ul

ul
  li
  li
/ul

/ul

li может быть и 10 и 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то концепция у вас быстро меняется )) В заголовке "*каждые 7 элементов*", а в вопросе уже "*каждые 2*". И еще, вас не смущает тот факт, что структура будет не валидной? **ul** может быть дочерним **li**-элемента, но не **ul**. В общем, [набросал вам пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/KS2Km/), а если все-таки хотите, чтоб **ul** был вложен в **ul**, то уберете лишние li из кода внутри метода wrapAll().

Comment: Извеняюсь за опечатку, писал просто быстро)), я понимаю что должно быть так <ul> <li> <ul> <li></li>  <li></li>  </ul></li></ul> ))) главное что вы поняли суть и помогли. Большое спасибо!!))

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали выше, код будет невалидный. Каждые два элемента списка нужно обернуть в свои теги `<ul></ul>`, а потом еще обернуть в `<li></li>`
Вот так, [например](http://jsfiddle.net/6DSUV/48/)

Comment: Тоже в принцепи имеет место быть)))

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrOfLi = document.getElementsByTagName("LI"); // берем 10 и 20 li
var length = arr.length; // сохраняем количество li
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0]; // берем твой ul главный
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
var subUl = document.createElement("UL"); // создаем внутренний ul
var subLi = document.createElement("LI"); // создаем li
subUl.appendChild(subLi); // присобачиваем li к ul
ul.appendChild(subUl); // присобачиваем внутренний ul с li ко внешнему ul
}
```